# How to automaticly call different nodes in the same launch file?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to have like some how automation in my launch file. I would like to call a node inside launch file while pressing for example button 1. For example pressing button 1(or entering 1) will run the node1 with the output parameters a,b,c. Pressing the button 2 (entering 2) will run the node2 in the same launch file. Any help how to implement this??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67963/how-to-automaticly-call-different-nodes-in-the-same-launch-file?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-07-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Launch files have limited built in run time decisions.  There are, however, [if and unless attributes for all tags](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML#if_and_unless_attributes).  Combined with the [arg tag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/arg), you could [pass in an argument at launch time](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools#Passing_in_args) to conditionally run either node1 or node2 from the same launch file. Maybe you could rig up some code or a script to pass one argument if button1 is pressed and another argument if button2 is pressed.

**EDIT**

Q: "So in my case an argument is a node, correct?" -@Astronaut

Not the node itself, but an arg on which node to launch. Something like:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="launch_node_1" default="true" />
    <node if="$(arg launch_node_1)" name="node1" .../>
    <node unless="$(arg launch_node_1)" name="node2" .../>
</launch>
```

Then a call of `roslaunch my_file.launch launch_node_1:=true` would launch node1 and a call of `roslaunch my_file.launch launch_node_1:=false` would launch node2

I've not yet used rqt_launch, but Dan is doubtless more experienced than I.

**EDIT 2:**

Q: So in a script I have to call first the launch file than the arguments in that launch file, true??And possible to launch more than two nodes? Like button1 will run node1, button2 will run node2, button3 runs node3 etc..

Yes, you will launch the launch file to run any combination of any number of nodes you want, based on whatever arguments you pass in.  A launch file is a one time thing, though. roslaunch will keep nodes alive if you tell it to, but it isn't constantly monitoring the status of the arguments. To run different nodes at different times, you shouldn't use a single launch file. It wasn't built for that.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-22**:
Thanks. So in my case an argument is a node, correct? So can rig up some code than can pass argument 1(node 1) if button 1 (for example keyboard button 1) is pressed. Correct?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-22**:
And using Qt would not be much easier and more elegant solution?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-22**:
So in a script I have to call first the launch file than the arguments in that launch file, true??And possible to launch more than two nodes? Like button1 will run node1, button2 will run node2, button3  runs node3 etc.. ??

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-23**:
And when I use the arguments in launch file means I have single launch file and can run different nodes based on the arguments value?? Here is no input from the keyboard taken into account, true?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at [rqt_launch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rqt_launch?distro=groovy)? It may be able to do at least some of what you want.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-07-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-22**:
No, didnt look at rqt_launch... But when I checked its only for Groovy. Im using ROS Fuerte. is that ok? Any documentation or tutorial regarding this problem implementation with  rqt_launch on Fuerte?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-22**:
You can download src of `rqt_launch`, or the entire metapackage it resides in. It should work on `fuerte`. We're not planning to merge back newer stuff into fuerte, which is planned to End-Of-Life soon.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-22**:
And rqt_launch is still missing many features some of which seem available on its GUI...working on those is on my todolist but not on the top..

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-07-22**:
So also no C++ src. any documentation or help how to use the src?